# Intuition of following the lowest curvature mode to find a saddle point on a PES

Tags: transition-state-theory

In this paper [A dimer method for finding saddle points on high dimensional potential surfaces using only first derivatives](https://aip.scitation.org/doi/10.1063/1.480097), it is mentioned that

> The saddle point is a maximum along the lowest curvature mode.

The curvature in this paper refers to the second derivate of the PES.

I know that mathematically, a saddle point minimizes the PES in all but one direction, and it is the highest point on the minimum energy path (MEP). But this cannot help me understand why the saddle point is a maximum along the lowest curvature mode.